# Structured bindings to get consecutive elements of a sub-vector without copying

Tags: c++, structured-bindings

I have a `std::vector<T> vec` where consecutive blocks of 3 elements are of interest. For ease of processing, I'd like to extract such elements. Currently, the code looks like:

```
const T& a = vec[i];
const T& b = vec[i + 1];
const T& c = vec[i + 2];
```

I'd like to use a structured binding to compress the extraction of `a`, `b`, `c` to a single line.

A simple option would be something along the lines of:

```
std::tuple<T, T, T> getElement(int i) {
    return std::make_tuple(vec[i], vec[i+1], vec[i+2]);
}

// ...
auto [a, b, c] = getElement(j);
```

The problem is that I would like to avoid useless copying of data. I'm not sure, but it seems that the vector elements will be copied here into the tuple. Would using `std::tuple<T&, T&, T&>` be an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would using `std::tuple<T&, T&, T&>` be an option?

It would, and there's already a utility for it in the standard library: [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).
It accepts an arbitrary number of references (to different types even), and returns a tuple of references to the same objects. So your use case can be condensed to

```
auto getElement(int i) {
    return std::tie(vec[i], vec[i+1], vec[i+2]);
}
```

Comment: Just to fill in... `std::tie` is pure gold.

Comment: Really nice! Is there any way to get rid of the auto return type and specify something more...concrete?

Comment: @Paul92 - You know the type of the objects, so you can specify the tuple of references if you wish. But personally, I consider `auto` more than justified here.

Comment: You're right - the return tuple was having const references, I tried with a tuple of references and got an error which confused me. For a short getter like this, I would agree. But the function is a bit larger and goes into a cpp. I think a declaration like `auto getElement(int i);` in a class is a bit confusing.